# building with Visual Studio 2019 but getting depend on MFC140U.dll

Tags: visual-studio, dll, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I have moved from VS2015 to VS2019. I've created a deployment and all is good locally, here on three machines. But when I shipped a test MSI out to an old laptop we got an MFC140.dll not found.  I found the dependency in one of my dlls, thought it had something to do with not moving it up to UNICODE. Did that and it still depends on MFC140U.dll

I do have

```
toolset       (VS 2019)vs142
SDK Version   10.0(latest installed)
```

I've googled and pulled hair out. But the lights are not coming on. Checked, and this is also happening to a second dll I build.

So I check another app that goes into the deployment. It does not use any of my dlls. Yet it also depends on MFC140U.dll as well as MFC142U.dll. The only libs linked in this one are BOOST and SQLITE3. And those don't have any MFC dependencies. This just adds to my confusion.

The only thing that would make sense to me is that a vs142 build has some 140 dependency and the deployment system is not picking that up. Note that deployment is not done with install shield as was done with vs2015.

Yes, I could fix it by shipping the MFC140U.dll but that just does not seem right. Either I, or Microsoft, has something wrong is all I can figure.

**UPDATE:**

I created a fresh MFC project with VS2019 and looked at the depends. Same thing, this is about Microsoft. And it looks like the deployment system includes MFC142x dlls but not the MFC140 that is required.

Comment: I assume you are not compiling with static MFC library. If you did then you don’t need to deploy the DLL. See your project settings.

Comment: I'm wondering if a static build is the way to go these days. It will bloat my deployment. I have several MFC dependent builds.

Comment: Static build is bad from a security point of view. MSFT can' fix security holes in the runtime that is statically linked to your app.

Comment: @zett42 I have always used static builds.

Comment: @zett42 I've researched this and yes, you are right. Our deployment stays up to date by using the vsredist. But I'm still having problems with the VS2019 packaging. That will be another question...

Comment: @AndrewTruckle These days, with [improved ABI compatibility of VC-Redist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019), I would use static builds only for portable and single-executable apps, where it is a key feature, that installation is not required. If you already have an installer, it usually isn't a problem to include a VC-Redist package and give your users the benefit of security patches through Windows Update.

Comment: @zett42 I would prefer to download and install the re-distributable if it was not installed by the installer because the redist file is 14MB and my current setup is 14MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention what your "deployment system" is, so I'm not sure what installer technology you are using here.

But your application or one of your DLL's has a dependency on MFC. If MFC isn't needed, you'll want to check your build settings on the exe or dll in question. The other item to check is if you are errantly including the afx.h header in your project. The afx.h has #pragma comment(lib, xxx) entries that resolve to the proper mfc140xxx.lib depending on your build options.

If the MFC dependency is legitimate, you should be installing the VC runtime components using the vsredist packages designed for just that purpose. These should be installed to your hard drive under a path similar to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.21.27702

Alternatively, you can download the latest using the following link:

[The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Sincerely,

Comment: Hi Ed, both applications mentioned are MFC. This is about the VS2015 dependency with a VS2019 build. The MFC142 dependency is expected, not the MFC140. The installer is what comes from Microsoft, `Extensions->Manage Extensions`. That the deployment system may not package the redists but I can wix them in if that is the case. I will link this post to the VS forum tomorrow, it is late.

Comment: I'll check, but I'm pretty sure the 142 redist is in the package. It worked fine on my wife's 7 machine, updates off, and no other MFC apps installed. About the only way she could have gotten the MFC142x dlls.

Comment: The latest vcredist packages do contain the v142 version of the vc runtime components (including MFC). And these are the ones you should be deploying. From VS 2015 through VS 2019, the filenames haven't changed, as the C++ team has committed not to break the ABI. The following contains the relevant details:

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks. This is making a lot more sense. I checked my wife's system32 folder. There is, after all, no MFC142! So the fallback is MFC140, even if a dependency for 142 shows up. Please make that your answer. [A good read on ABI.](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/stablecplusplusabi-333927.html) I guess this means that MFC is no longer under development.